# Access Virtual Console via SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, x11

Let's imagine we have this situation - we have 2 PCs some distance apart (one is at home, the other in an office). The PC in the office had restarted and awaits login (via virtual console, no fancy login manager; it's running Arch btw :)). Its SSH daemon is running so the PC at home can reach it with no problems. The question is how the PC at home can (via SSH) access the virtual console #1 on the office PC, login (if needed) and then run `startx`, so X will run as usual (as if it was ran locally). As you know running `startx` directly from SSH terminal doesn't work.

Comment: Why do you need to start X remotely?  You won't be able to do anything useful with it anyway.

Comment: I will run x0vncserver and then connect to it with TigerVnc client. Running vncserver "unnatached" to the physical display is undesirable for me

Comment: Does the office PC have [Lights Out Management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-band_management), such as iLO or iDRAC? Or, does its kernel support the `vnc` and `vncpassword` options?

Comment: The office PC doesn't have Light Out Management. I'm not aware of vnc options to the kernel. It's a standart Arch distribution (kernel is not customized by me)

Answer (score 2):

You can change your virtual terminal and start X11 like this:

```
sudo chvt 1        # change to virtual terminal 1
sudo startx        # start X11
```

Note that `chvt` also allows you to run `fim` (and probably `fbi`) via an `ssh` session:

```
ssh somewhere
sudo chvt 1
sudo fim -a -T1 image.png
```